# Knockout table style binding - Table style dont updated

Tags: knockout.js

What I want to achieve is, if my ajax call return data, I will hide one table and show another table by passing **display** value to **none** and **normal**

see my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da7yL37h/)** for the live sample.

Ok guys, here is my table html :

```
    <table data-bind="style: { 'display': MainVisible }" id="tblDisplayBenefit" style="border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:2px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="padding:2px;width:5px">No.</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:250px">&nbsp;Benefit</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:100px">Detail</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:100px">Description</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:20px">Total Days</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:120px">&nbsp;Claimed</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:120px">Approved</th>
            <th style="padding:6px;width:120px">Excess</th>
            <th style="padding:7px;width:100px">Reduce Max Limit </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: benefitData">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:2px;text-align:right;width:5px" data-bind="text: RegId"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;width:250px" data-bind="text: BenefitDisplay"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;width:100px" data-bind="text: RoomClassDesc"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;width:100px" data-bind="text: ManualDesc"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;text-align:right;width:20px" data-bind="text: TotalDays"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;text-align:right;width:120px" data-bind="text: ClaimAmount"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;text-align:right;width:120px" data-bind="text: ClaimApproved"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px;text-align:right;width:120px" data-bind="text: ClaimExcess"></td>
            <td style="padding:7px;text-align:center;width:100px"> <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" data-bind="checked: FgReduceMaxLimit" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right"><b>TOTAL&nbsp;</b></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;border-spacing:6px;padding:6px;text-align:right" data-bind="text: totalClaimed"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;border-spacing:6px;padding:6px;text-align:right" data-bind="text: totalApproved"></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid;border-spacing:6px;padding:6px;text-align:right" data-bind="text: totalExcess"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<table data-bind="style: { 'display': isVisible }" id="tblWarningClaim" style="border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:2px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td style="border:1px solid;padding:6px">No Claim Data Found.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my Javascript snippet code :

```
// Global Variable and Function

var testView = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.isVisible = ko.observable('normal');
    self.MainVisible = ko.observable('normal');

    // my other observable variable and function

}

//--------------------------------------------------------



var VM = new testView();
VM.MainVisible = 'normal';
VM.isVisible = 'none';

// My AJAX Call, store the result into ManualRegClaimData
ManualRegClaimData = $.parseJSON(rows.d);

var ClaimExist = ManualRegClaimData[0].BenefitDisplay;

        if (ClaimExist == null) { // No Claim data
            VM.benefitData.removeAll();
            VM.isVisible = 'normal';
            VM.MainVisible = 'none';
            console.log(VM.isVisible, VM.MainVisible);
        }
        else { // Claim data exist
            VM.benefitData.removeAll();
            VM.isVisible = 'none';
            VM.MainVisible = 'normal';
            console.log(VM.isVisible, VM.MainVisible);

        }
```

I have checked my JavaScript function return value, and it is already running well by return first option if no data return, and second option if data return exists.
**see the console.log**

I have tried second condition, it ran well. But if the first condition occurs, Seems my table style dont binded with the value from knockout variable.

Please suggest me a way to fix this, I have traced from yesterday but still no clue why my table style wont updated.

Thanks! I will wait your suggest..

Comment: can you add the smallest possible version of your issue in http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link? That will make it easier for others to help you out.

Comment: see my question part, I have been added my jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `self.isVisible` as observable.
To set value to `self.isVisible`, you should do `VM.isVisible('none')`; and **not** `VM.isVisible = 'none'`. Please check whether you have done the same for other observables also.

Updated part of your code below. Please see how the VM.MainVisible and VM.isVisible is set by using brackets.

```
var testView = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.isVisible = ko.observable('normal');
    self.MainVisible = ko.observable('normal');

    // my other observable variable and function

}

//--------------------------------------------------------



var VM = new testView();
VM.MainVisible('normal');
VM.isVisible('none');
```

I have updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/da7yL37h/2/
If you set var TestInput = 1;, you should see one record and if you set any other value, you will see "No claim records" message.

Comment: you just got my code error with : isVisible is not a function.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I've update the answer to make it clear. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: Updated your jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/da7yL37h/2/. If you set var TestInput = 1; you will see one row displayed. I also added ko.applyBindings(VM) which was not added in your version of jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry late reply. I will check a second

Comment: Please check the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/da7yL37h/2/. Update the TestInput value from 2 to 1.